# What happened to the Warrior Lodges of loyalist Legions during the Horus Heresy?

Tags: warhammer-40k, horus-heresy

In Warhammer 40k, the Warrior Lodges were secret groups amongst the Space Marines Legions during the Great Crusade. They presented themselves as a transversal organization, where official hierarchy were abolished and where Marines from all ranks and Legions could speak freely and fraternize. The lodges originated from the Word Bearers and quickly spread amongst the Legions. The dark face of the lodges were that they were actually organizing a parallel organization, to prepare the Marines to the idea of Horus' betrayal and monitor which Marines would follow the Warmaster and which ones would remain loyal to the Emperor.

I think there were lodges in most of the Legions. What happened to the lodges that were part of a Loyalist Legions? I don't remember any mention of this in the Horus Heresy books (I read a fair part of them, but not all).

Did the Loyalists (save their lodge members) ignore the involvement of the lodges in the Heresy and the lodges could stay undercover, undermining the Loyalist Legions from inside?

Or were they purged at the beginning of the Heresy?

Answer (score 7):

#### We're never really told, but we can make some reasonably well informed assumptions...

We know at least the White Scars [continued the practice](http://wh40k.lexicanum.com/wiki/Warrior_Lodge) for some time post-Heresy:

> The lodges also fostered the appearance of traitor elements within those Legions that remained loyal as a whole during the war, such as the White Scars

Once the Heresy began, among loyalist marines, it suddenly would have become obvious what the lodges had become and they would have been very closely linked with the traitors. So it's reasonable to assume that they were quickly dissolved.

You'd also have to assume that the [Codex Astartes](http://wh40k.lexicanum.com/wiki/Codex_Astartes), which forced legions to break into much smaller chapters after the Heresy, would also ban the idea of Warrior Lodges completely, as without the lodges, the traitors would of had a much tougher time spreading their new ideology amongst the legions.

Comment: Out of interest how would, the ultramarines for instance, have known that the subversion started in the lodges?

Comment: @Liath I think it would have been common knowledge throughout all the loyalist legions _after_ Istavaan. I mean, if some of your friends were talking about how annoying one specific friend is, then he turns up dead on Istavaan III and they have all vanished, you'd at least be a little suspicious... I can't say for sure exactly how it went down with each legion though.

Answer (score -1):

Not all legions had lodges and as far as has been shown so far the only loyalist legions that have been shown to have a lodge was the white scars, for that matter not all traitor legions had lodges.

Some legions had organisations that pre dated the word bearers lodge idea and so the “lodges” never took hold.

The only loyalist legion that we see lodges took hold in was the white scars and we see the Khan punishes all those that turned traitor so probably purging then.

Commissar Ciaphas Cain made a point of lecturing his students at the Schola Progenium about it, the better for them to spot, and hopefully head off, the development of Traitor Guard units.”